# Compare date from CSV to reference date

Tags: csv, powershell-3.0

I am parsing a CSV file using a PowerShell script. I would like to compare date read from the CSV file with current date and do certain operation or exit processing script. Can any one help me on below issue?

Date in the CSV file is like below:
Trading Date:,2015-12-14

```
$CurrentTimeStamp = Get-Date
$TradeDate = $CurrentTimeStamp.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$CheckDate = $TradeDate
```

TradeDate is as above:

```
$FileTradeDate = $Cols[1]
$TradeDate = $FileTradeDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
if ($TradeDate -ne $CheckDate) {
  $host.Exit()
} else {
  $TradeDate = $FileTradeDate
  LogWrite $TradeDate
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".
At \\multinasdub301\Software\SysAdmin\WebDownloads\ProcessUBSFrescoCCYHDG.ps1:139 char:5
+                 $TradeDate = $FileTradeDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data read from a CSV file is already a string, and from your example it appears to already be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`, so no need to convert it a string again. You need to format `$checkDate` with the same format, though, otherwise the strings will never match:

```
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Or you could parse the date from the CSV to an actual `DateTime` value and compare two dates:

```
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).Date
$culture   = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='Trading Date';e={
      [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'Trading Date', 'yyyy-MM-dd', $culture)
    }} -Exclude 'Trading Date' |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.'Trading Date' -eq $CheckDate) {
      $TradeDate = $FileTradeDate
      LogWrite $TradeDate
    }
  }
```

Comment: tried first option and gives me below error:

`Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost] doesn't contain a method
named 'Exit'.
At \\multinasdub301\Software\SysAdmin\WebDownloads\ProcessUBSFrescoFI.ps1:148 char:6
+                     $Host.Exit()
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: That's unrelated to your question, but use `exit` instead of `$host.Exit()`. Or rather, don't exit but invert the condition and do nothing if the dates aren't equal. See updated answer.